# Menu add item or edit item not available for users with admin rights

Tags: routes, forms

I'm working on a Drupal core 6.26 website and I'm unable to debug or find an answer for this problem.

I have a group of users, let's call it GroupTest that has permissions enabled for administer menu.

When trying to edit a menu item or add a menu item with a user from GroupTest group, the add item / edit item form (actually just the fieldset Menu settings) is hidden by an inline "display: none;" style. The only thing visible is the save button.

However, this doesn't happen when I'm using the admin (1) user. The form is displayed just fine.

I've tried different approaches to debug this, looking for hook_form_alter in custom modules/themes that might be modifying this, even for javascript code that would hide the form.

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any custom/forked modules installed on the site? Themes?

Try changing the theme; if it works with another theme (let's say Bartik) then the problem is somewhere in your theme.

If the above doesn't work, clone the site and start disabling the modules one by one; eventually you will find the one which is causing the problem.